# How to make Highcharts drilldown to work with multiple columns

Tags: jquery, highcharts

This is an old question from Highcharts forum, 
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.highslide.com%2Fforum%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D9%26t%3D16573&ei=J_2GUM7fEoSC9QT0lICoCA&usg=AFQjCNGq_GxmSd0YUxWUyy96UHLZA0zb9w&sig2=RzAkhldNbvCowk8I1kmRVg

I'm implementing it today and the solutions on the forum post worked. However, I needed to make a custom solution, which is 2-level drilldown chart with 3 columns. To clarify, the solution provided on the forum only works really well with 2 columns on first chart, then 1 column on the drilldown. My chart requires 3 columns on both initial chart and drilldown chart.

I couldn't quite understand the drilldown transition and how it works so it is very hard for me to customize the code. There is also quite a bit of duplicate code with the implementation, so if anyone has a better understanding of Highcharts drilldown, please feel free to share some advice on how I have to make it work.

The key part of the code is

```
            var drilldown = this.drilldown;

            if (drilldown) { // drill down
               setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
            } else { // restore
                 setChart(name, categories, data);

             }
```

and setChart():

```
function setChart(name, categories, data) {
        chart.counters.color = 0;
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        while (chart.series.length > 0){
            chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            chart.addSeries({
                name: name[i],
                data: data[i]
            });
        }
    }
```

How to determine this.drilldown and input for setChart() are the keys to make it right.

The fiddle I have tried is: http://jsfiddle.net/dTkh4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is at

```
var drilldown = this.drilldown;

if (drilldown) { // drill down
   setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data);

} else { // restore
   setChart([name1, name2, name3], categories1, [data1, data2, data3]);
}
```

To make drilldown view showing 3 split columns, drilldown.name and drilldown.data needs to be a nested array of 3 and each child array has values for each category. For the restore part, name3 is added to show 3 columns upon restore instead of 2.